# Dygraph issue showing Oct-17 on the x-axis

Tags: axis, dygraphs

Does Dygraph have any problem with showing `Oct-17` month on the X-axis? I have the xts object named `L`, generated as below:

```
L1 <- xts(x=1,order.by = as.Date("2017-09-01"))

L2 <- xts(x=4,order.by = as.Date("2017-10-01"))

L=rbind(L1,L2)
```

Now, if you run

```
Dygraph (L)
```

You'll see that `Oct-17` is replaced with `Sep-17` in the output plot.

Does anyone have any idea why it happened? It's fine with any other month.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with end values. In this case you have created the object L with two dates: "2017-09-01", "2017-10-01". The value Oct-17 has not been replaced with Sep-17 as your final value is October 1st and Oct-17 would be after your actual end date.

In this case the October label on xaxis is hidden and can be shown by simply using rangePad which specifies the amount of extra space (in pixels) around the value range to ensure points at the edges remain visible.

```
dygraph(L) %>%
   dyAxis("x", rangePad= 4)
```

I have also used a package: dyplyr to be able to use %>% (a.k.a: pipe) operator in R.